# Regex match a row copied from webpage

Tags: html, regex

[image]

so if I copy a table to clipboard directly, it give the following result:

```
Dirty1057
SUPQB
1
Occupied
Checked Out
    
    
 (Unchecked) Priority
 (Unchecked) Linen Change
DEP
View
Select
Out of Order1060
SUPQV
1
Vacant
Checked Out
    
    
 (Unchecked) Priority
 (Unchecked) Linen Change
```

I'm trying to extract 3 to 4 digit number (room number) if only if the row is "Dirty" room and consist "Occupied" and "Checked Out".
I wrote this regex

```
Dirty(\d{3,4})(.|\n)*?Vacant\nChecked Out
```

as you can see it shouldn't match any result since there are not Dirty + Vacant + Checked Out room. Is it possible to write a regex to match these criteria?

Comment: Better add the link you try to scrape or the source HTML. Regex is not the tool to parse HTML alone.

Comment: @GillesQuénot I don't know what technology this webpage used, the url is static which never changes. Also I am not planning to extract from the html because the id is dynamic which keep changing. That is why I can only copy it from Clipboard

Comment: Let us take a look. Share the URL. This post will certainly be closed/deleted because it's not a reproductible question.

Comment: @GillesQuénot I truly can't, not that I don't want. it required login

Comment: **So share the source HTML**

Comment: Copy pasting is OFF topic. Not reproductible, not interesting in another context than your very specific needs. SO is a professional Q/A website. Better ask ChatGPT if you insist to not doing the things the proper way.

Comment: Did you mean, it should consist of `Checked Out` and `Occupied` or `Vacant` like in your regex attempt. For the latter try something like [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/j5BD2o/1) or [that one](https://regex101.com/r/TPvZ7a/1) if `Vacant` and `Checked Out` can occur non adjacent as well. It is supposed to not skipping over lines which don't start with a non-whitespace character.

Comment: very impressive, exactly what I've needed, I have optimised it became
`Dirty(\d{3,4})\n(?:\S+\n)+Vacant\nChecked Out`, I wonder can it be even lesser steps (efficient)